# Problem about font encoding in PDF/A generation

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, fonts, pdfa

So here is my problem : 
I'm currently working on an java application that will archive document in a PDF/A-1. I'm using PdfBox for pdf generation and when I can't generate a valid PDF/A-1 pdf, because of the font. The font is embedded inside the pdf file but this website : https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx tell me that this is not a valid PDF/A because of :

> The key Encoding has a value Identity-H which is prohibited.

I look on internet on what is this Identity-H encoding and it seem that it's the way that font are encoded, like the ansi encoding.

I've already tried to get different font like Helvetica or arial unicode Ms but nothing work, there is alway this Identity-H encoding.I'm a bit lost with all this mess in encoding so if someone can explain me it'll be great. Also here is the code I write to embedded a font in the pdf :

```
 // load the font as this needs to be embedded
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fontfile), true);

if (!font.isEmbedded())
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("PDF/A compliance requires that all fonts used for"
                    + " text rendering in rendering modes other than rendering mode 3 are embedded.");
        }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This is weird - the PDF generated with the CreatePDFA example validates there.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: don't use "getClassLoader()", this brings problems with certain java versions. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4428

Comment: Could you 1) try the  CreatePDFA example yourself, 2) share the file that doesn't validate?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I used the example of Apache and it work ! I don't know why because the file and the code was the but, if it work. My last problem on PDF/A generation deal with embedded files. I try to make PDF/A3-a, and I got on last error when I validate it : "The key AFRelationship is required but missing". I checked on internet but no-one say how to set this in pdfbox.

Comment: Use `dictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("AFRelationship"), COSName.getPDFName("Supplement"))` or whatever the correct value is. (It can be Source, Data, Alternative, Supplement, EncryptedPayload, FormData, Schema or Unspecified)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr what's the object type of dictionary ?

Comment: A `COSDictionary`. You usually get it by calling `getCOSObject()` on your element. (some element in that file attachment structure. The best would be you open an existing PDF/A-3 file with PDFDebugger to see which one it is)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you so much it work ! I have a last problem. I didn't see anyone talking about it so if you can help me that will be great ! I get this error when try to validate the PDF/A : "File specification 'Test.xlsx' not associated with an object.". I use the version 3-a of PDF/A to allow embedded file I didn't see any solution to fixe it. Thank for your help :)

Comment: I don't have a direct answer but see here: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/201312.mbox/%3C20131229225012.07b8100f@ray-laptop%3E and https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Parts-2-and-3-rules "Each file attachment in a PDF/A-3 document must be referenced from one of the following objects in the PDF document" if that doesn't help I recommend you create a new question.

Comment: Re the original question, I suggest you answer it yourself. I still wonder what the difference between your PDF and the example PDF was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :

I used the example of apache : CreatePDFA ( I have no clue why that work and not my code ) : [Example in examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/apache/pdfbox/2.0.16/pdfbox-2.0.16-src.zip)

I add to fit the PDF/A-3 requirement :

```
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setLanguage("en-US");

PDMarkInfo mark = new PDMarkInfo(); // new PDMarkInfo(page.getCOSObject());
PDStructureTreeRoot treeRoot = new PDStructureTreeRoot();
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setMarkInfo(mark);
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setStructureTreeRoot(treeRoot);
doc.getDocumentCatalog().getMarkInfo().setMarked(true);

PDDocumentInformation info = doc.getDocumentInformation();
info.setCreationDate(date);
info.setModificationDate(date);
info.setAuthor("KairosPDF");
info.setProducer("KairosPDF");
info.setCreator("KairosPDF");
info.setTitle("Generated PDf");
info.setSubject("PDF/A3-A");
```

Here is my code to embedded a file to the pdf :

```
private final PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
private final PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode efTree = new PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode();
private final PDDocumentNameDictionary names = new PDDocumentNameDictionary(doc.getDocumentCatalog());
private final Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> efMap = new HashMap<>();

public void addFile(PDDocument doc, File child) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(child.getPath());

    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();

    //first create the file specification, which holds the embedded file
    PDComplexFileSpecification fs = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
    fs.setFileUnicode(child.getName());
    fs.setFile(child.getName());
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    PDEmbeddedFile ef = new PDEmbeddedFile(doc, is);

    //Setting
    ef.setSubtype("application/octet-stream");
    ef.setSize((int) file.length() + 1);
    ef.setCreationDate(date);
    ef.setModDate(date);
    COSDictionary dictionary = fs.getCOSObject();
    dictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("AFRelationship"), COSName.getPDFName("Data"));

    fs.setEmbeddedFile(ef);

    efMap.put(child.getName(), fs);
    efTree.setNames(efMap);

    names.setEmbeddedFiles(efTree);
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().setNames(names);
    is.close();
}
```

The only problem left is this error from the validation :

> File specification 'Test.txt' not associated with an object.

Hope it'll help some.